# SQL tool for mirroring data from live database to test?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Currently, we have a several environments, but mainly we have a live environment and a test environment as most do.

It seems our test environment we are always having issues with having good data in our test environment.  Largely because our test sql environment is maintained by a bunch of loose scripts that are not maintained very well.  Obviously, one course of action is to maintain these more efficiently, that is not going to happen we have found.

So, I am looking for a tool that would help with this.  Has anyone found or used such a tool?

Any advice or direction would be greatly appreciated.  This is really a thorn in our developer's sides.

**Update**Our main issue is that test structures often differ from live and we need an automated solution that handles this, i.e. when a table has more columns in test than in live.  Updating question to reflect this thank you for your answer.

Comment: We use CruiseControl to handle deploying our SQL scripts from our SVN repository to numerous test databases.

Comment: The Red Gate tools are good for diffing and keeping things in sync; both schema and data.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Transfer of Data is concerned use SSMS import and export data wizard.If source and destination tables names and schema is same Data transfer is a breeze.I use it quite often  never faced any problem (use identity insert option if there is any identity col).

and Script generation feature of SSMS is not that bad either. Normally i have to edit 'Create Database' and 'create Users' parts of the script manually.

Comment: Our main issue is that test structures often differ from live and we need an automated solution that handles this, i.e. when a table has more columns in test than in live.  Updating question to reflect this thank you for your answer.